# Synonyms for "overwhelming force"

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

I'm looking for other expressions that describe "overwhelming force" as applied to the "shock and awe" American military doctrine or different kinds of asymmetric warfare.

Trivial sentence:

> The empire attacked the rebel base with __________ (overwhelming force?).

Comment: "To some in the Arab and Muslim countries, [Shock and Awe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_and_awe) is terrorism by another name; to others, a crime that compares unfavourably with September 11."

Comment: @Cascabel that's ok as a political comment and will not judge it one way or the other.  I'm just interested in similar expressions that match the intended meaning of the phrase, everything else is out of scope

Comment: "massive firepower response" ?

Comment: @Graffito not a fan of it but feel free to add it as a response. you might get votes and even an accepted answer. and to explain why i find it a bit not suited is the fact that "response" implies some kind of defensive stance when the initial term is all about full blown attack (political motivation aside)

Comment: Although “ … with **all its might**” probably overstates it and even then doesn’t necessarily imply, as “overwhelming” does, that it was more than enough, you might consider it until something better comes along.

Comment: @AZ: I intentionally used the term "response" because of the context of unconventional conflicts, where brute force is one of the options to combat terrorism. I was not thinking of a deliberate use of brute force against a poorly armed opponent (e.g. Russian forces invading Latvia).

Comment: It's slightly dated (more appropriate for 1950) and maybe very slightly racist in tone, but there's "Mongol horde".

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that came to mind to fill the blank in your example sentence was:
 “ … with **all its might**.”

However, that phrase would probably be overstating the actual/literal extent of the attack and even so overstated, it doesn’t necessarily imply, as “overwhelming” does, that the power of the attacking force disproportionately exceeded that of the force being attacked.

Granted, your use of "empire” and “rebel [base]” in the example sentence would probably lead one to assume that “all the might” of an Empire would be more than enough to defeat/overwhelm “all the might” of a rebel base.  As you say yourself, however, your example is not only just an example, but a trivial one at that.

All that to try to say that without the “clues” of “empire” and “rebel base,” attacking “with all its might” does not guarantee that the defender’s might is not equal to or even greater than that of the attacker.

---

I do, however, think that replacing “force” with [the noun sense of **“might”**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/might#might_Noun_200) would be a good first step in finding a suitable synonym for “overwhelming force” and that combining "might" with the [complete/thorough/extreme sense of  **“crushing”**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/crushing) could overcome the problems with “all its might”:

> The empire attacked the rebel base with [its] **crushing might**.

---

> **Might** (from *oxforddictionaries.com*)
>      NOUN
>     [mass noun] Great and impressive power or strength, especially of a nation, large
>   organization, or natural force:
>     ‘a convincing display of military
>   might’

---

> **Crushing**  (from * macmillandictionary.com*)
>    ADJECTIVE
>      1  complete and achieved very easily
>     a crushing defeat/victory
>   Complete and thorough: thorough, total, pure...
>
> 2  very severe
>     a crushing blow:
>      It’s a crushing blow for
>   the president’s foreign policy.
>      Serious, severe and extreme: the
>   nuclear option, serious, severe...

Here are two example uses of “crushing might” that seem to me to be synonymous, or nearly so, with “overwhelming force”:

> “The coordinated assaults against Germany which had been fixed upon at Yalta
>   went forward with [crushing
>   might.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=CQzWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA561&dq=%22with+crushing+might%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq-eCpy43SAhXklVQKHbpLAh8Q6AEITDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22with%20crushing%20might%22&f=false)
>   (from *Churchill-Roosevelt-Stalin: The War They Waged and the Peace
>   They Sought* By Herbert Fei, via *GoogleBooks*)

---

> “[We are rendered] helpless [and] paralyzed [with] the [crushing
>   might](https://books.google.com/books?id=JIeTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&lpg=PT171&dq=%22crushing+might%22+definition&source=bl&ots=n0uVkems1k&sig=am2x3p8S5czaTe-Sys5ODh4vgI0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii0NWmyY3SAhUlqFQKHQvPBxsQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=%22crushing%20might%22&f=false)
>   of the state … hurled against any man who refuses to accept the new
>   Faith.”
>   (from *Fictions of Power in English Literature: 1900-1950* By Lee
>   Horsley (quoting  Czeslaw  Milosz from *The Captive Mind*) via *Google
>   Books*)

Comment: Agree with "all it's might" not necessarily meaning overwhelming force. If the rebel forces attacked the Empire with "all it's might", it would hardly be overwhelming.

Comment: @iMerchant That’s a great point and you mentioning it actually made me realize that “with all its might” is very (most?) often associated with unsuccessful (albeit valiant/all out) endeavors (“[tried] with all its might [but/in vain]”), which association makes it even less suitable as an across-the-board replacement for “overwhelming force.”

Comment: Also “crushing force”

Comment: Crush is very a propos here since I think Tarkin says something like: “ This bickering is pointless. Now Lord Vader will provide us with the location of the hidden Rebel fortress. We will then crush the Rebellion with one swift stroke.”

Answer (score 0):

> The empire attacked the rebel base with ***an iron hand/fist***.

ODO:

> **[iron fist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/iron_fist)** (*also* **iron hand**)
>   *NOUN*
>
> Used in reference to the exercise of power in an oppressive or
>   ruthless way.
>
> ‘The participants expressed concern at the growing menace of terrorism
>   across the globe and the need to put it down with an iron hand.’

Comment: Not sure that's really appropriate - iron hand/fist is normally applied to a broad policy rather than a single specific action.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is **overkill**. One of its definitions specifically refers to weapons:

> the capability to deploy more weapons, esp nuclear weapons, than is necessary to ensure military advantage
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/overkill)</sub>

For example:

> With MIRVs, a disarming first-strike could theoretically be launched with only a fraction of the available launchers and possibly with **overkill**.
>   <sub>[International Encyclopedia of Military History](https://books.google.com/books?id=ELDlCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT955)</sub>

Comment: It's the difference between dominance and eradication.